# Java KeyEvent comparison - is arg0 equal to a specific key

Tags: java, comparison, keylistener, keyevent

I have created a new KeyListener, defined as following:

```
...
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.equals(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) || (arg0.equals(KeyEvent.VK_R))) {
        System.out.println("Enter or R key typed.");
        } else {
        System.out.println("Something else typed.");
    }
}
...
```

What I actually want to do is to call a method every time when the Enter key or 'R' is typed in.

My Problem: No matter what I type in, the if case is never triggered. It always jumps to the else case. What it the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: when, where, and how you used KeyListener, for better help sooner edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare the input with `KeyEvent.xxx` values, you need to use [the `getKeyCode` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyCode%28%29), which returns an `int` when you capture `keyPressed` or `keyReleased` events - you can then compare the value with a `KeyEvent.xxx`. If you want to use a `keyTyped` event, you can use the `getKeyChar` method but it will not capture some keys (action or modifier keys for example) - this should work for example:

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_R) {
        System.out.println("Enter or R key typed.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Something else typed.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The keyTyped only works in controls like JTextField or JTextArea, you may be looking for keyPressed instead. If that's not the case you might want to give more context.